# Rails 4, nested forms, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I need to create revisions for products, so I have to move editable information in different table

I created nested form, but having troubles saving data: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

As I understand, the problem is because of the naming, but I tried to call it product_infos, product_infos_attributes, etc... nothing is working

I also tried to change the behavior, by changing

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = false
```

but I'm still getting this exception

it works fine if I will change .create to .new and will assign all data manually, but there are a lot of fields, I'd rather use mass assignment

is there a way to get the name of the field(s) which cause the problem?

**Code:**

controller:

```
def create
  product = Product.new(product_params)

  if product.save params[:product].merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
    flash[:success] = t('msg.saved')
    redirect_to product_path(product)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def product_params
  params[:product][:slug] = make_slug(params[:product][:product_info][:caption])
  params.require(:product).permit(:image, product_infos: [:caption, :description])
end
```

model (product):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_infos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_infos    

  def save(params)
    self.user_id = params[:user_id]
    self.slug = params[:slug]

    if super
      # I have this error here
      revision = self.product_infos.create(params[:product_info])

      params[:image].each do |file|
        self.product_images.create(:image => file)
      end

      true
    end
  end
end
```

model (product_info):

```
class ProductInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for @product, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :product_info do |i| %>
      <%= i.label :caption %>
      <%= i.text_field :caption, class: 'form-control', required: 'required' %>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Error:

```
    ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ProductsController#create
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Extracted source (around line #57):
55
56
57
58
59
60


    if super
      revision = self.product_infos.new(params[:product_info])
      revision.caption = params[:product_info][:caption]
      revision.coordinates = params[:product_info][:coordinates]
      revision.user_id = params[:user_id]

Rails.root: /Users/lasoweq/Sites/ruby/eshop

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/product.rb:57:in 'save'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:22:in 'create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Iwg5hdVB+5aAt+Mij8Tg7mMJv+lUr1RXzKciwRVC/ATmtU1FH3odLNaNDhssWz8vbUK+YSTvT0ErB+3cAI5/Tg==",
 "product"=>{"product_info"=>{"caption"=>"Test123",
 "coordinates"=>"13.727685539497559,
100.63547114393305",
 "description"=>"<p>adasdasdasd</p>",
 "sizes"=>"asdasdasd",
 "height"=>"asdasd",
 "admission"=>"zxczxcz",
 "free_admission"=>"0",
 "custom_info"=>"zxczxczxc"},
 "categories"=>["",
 "3"],
 "image"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd529922c18 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/yt/dtw20h393hvd4xfwcjzhcqxr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150623-76404-c0nkwa.jpg>,
 @original_filename="GrizzlyBear1920x12005-23-2011_12_51_12_PM.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[image][]\"; filename=\"GrizzlyBear1920x12005-23-2011_12_51_12_PM.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
 #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd529922ab0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/yt/dtw20h393hvd4xfwcjzhcqxr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150623-76404-1si889i.jpg>,
 @original_filename="lion.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[image][]\"; filename=\"lion.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]},
 "commit"=>"Сохранить"}
```

Comment: Please update your post with model code with associations

Comment: sorry, forgot about this

Comment: Try changing `<%= f.fields_for :product_info do |i| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :product_infos do |i| %>`

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: @Pavan good catch! That is most likely it, you should add that as an answer :)

Comment: I already tried this, if I will change it to product_infos I will get empty form. Fields are not showing

Comment: Why you have `def save(params)` in your `product` model? what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: And also why you have `:description` when you are not saving it with the `form`?

Comment: it is simplified, there are more than 50 fields, I checked them all, all fields are listed in full version of controller

Comment: there are some other actions, I have to modify some data, so I have to override `save` function

Comment: Ok. How are you saving the `:image`? I can't see it in the `form`.

Comment: I use paperclip to save `image`. I just kept this field to show that I have fields outside `fields_for`. If I will comment block `revision = self.product_infos.create(params[:product_info])` it works fine, but obviously doesn't create the revision

Comment: Can you please post the complete error with params?

Comment: updated question with complete error

Comment: I haven't found the correct name for this permitted parameters, had to user .each with model.send "#{key}=", value. Not the best solution, but at least it works

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your associations and the database models are properly set. (belongs_to for the product_info model and has_many for the product model)

You have to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_infos` to your product model, to allow nested attributes. The parameter whitelist in the controller can be a problem causer, but the seem properly defined in your case.

Try adding the line above to the model.

Comment: sorry, I forgot about this, I've update my code, I already have this line in my model

Comment: it might be worth looking into the nested_form gem from Ryan Bates. It really makes this easy. While it works with Rails 4, it's a bit older.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `product` with `has_many` relation to `product_infos`,so this line

```
<%= f.fields_for :product_info do |i| %>
```

should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :product_infos do |i| %>
```

And also you have to change `:product_infos` to `:prodcut_infos_attributes` in your `product_params` method

Comment: if I will use `product_infos`, fields are not showing. All block `fields_for` are missing then